# Replace an element in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can we `replace` an element in spark scala shell?

for eg: 
`val t= sc.parallelize(Seq(("100",List("2","-4","NA","6","8","2"))))`

I would like to replace NA with 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try following to replace the `NA` with 0 but will give you a new `RDD`.

```
scala> val t= sc.parallelize(Seq(("100",List("2","-4","NA","6","8","2"))))
t: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[String])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:21
scala> val newRDD = t.map( x => (x._1,x._2.map{case "NA" => 0; case x => x }))
newRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[Any])] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:23

scala> newRDD.collect
res5: Array[(String, List[Any])] = Array((100,List(2, -4, 0, 6, 8, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you parallelize the sequence the spark creates an RDD of the provided value.
This RDD is stored across the cluster in spark. The nature of RDD is immutable, 
The other approach could be that you can filter out the "NA" values from the RDD
map them to Int and multiply each element to zero.
And union the filtered RDD to RDD including the not "NA" elements.

Sample Code

```
val t= sc.parallelize(Seq(("100",List("2","-4","NA","6","8","2"))))
val a = t.map(i => i._2).filter(i => i.contains("NA"))
val b = t.map(i => i._2).filter(i => !i.contains("NA")).map(i => (i*0))
val d = a.union(b)
```